# Left Navigation Menu creation in liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I created a left menu bar by using panel pages, I applied CSS (for displaying ), I added available portlet in panel.

Now, I have to put ordering(as per my requirement).

for ex:test,abc,bcd,efg these are the portlets,by default it showing abc,efg,test,bcd
but i want to show it as my order(postition change).how can to achieve this in panel?

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you give more information about code here or snapshot?

Comment: Hi pankaj,i try to add snapshot,but i dnt knw how to add..Let me explain clearly:I created a left menu bar by using panel pages..in panel pages i added some wars what i want,now here problem is i want to show the war files into my order,how i can do tht

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: i try to add my image,but it showing tht at least ten reputation after tht only i can add image

Comment: I have seen code at `\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\layout_configuration\view.jsp and view_category.jsp`, it sorts category and portlets under it on its title only.

Comment: Panel.jsp in same folder,can i add any changes there regarding sorting

Comment: Or else can i add code for interchanging link postions?